# Navigating JSON files with different arrays

Tags: javascript, json

So I have a json file that I fetch. This JSON file has several arrays for different graphs I'm doing.

```
Object
computer_skills: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
world_countries: (18) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
languages: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

How do I assign a JS object/array to each of the categories

so far I have the data fetching and coming up like above. Now I want to assign it to arrays of key/value  pairs. So I would have 3 datasets to add to the 3 graphs.

```
var vcomputerskills  = [];
fetch(myRequest)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

  vcomputerskills =  data.computer_skills;
  });
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do.

Comment: what does `data` look like? what is your expected rsult look like

Answer (score 0):

You can't create new variables dynamically at runtime but you have several options:

- Reference the data object from inside the promise

```js
var datasets
// ...
.then(data => {
  datasets =  data;
});
```

- Assign them to the top object (`window` in the browser or `global` in Node.js). Having global variables is not recommended as a general practice but is an option for some cases. For example:

```js
Object.keys(data).forEach((dataKey) => {
  window[dataKey] = data[dataKey];
});
```

- Using more recent features of EcmaScript (supported in Node.js 10 and all major browsers):

```js
const fn = async () => {
   const data = await fetch(myRequest).then(response => response.json())
}
```